# Problema con InsertCommand en SqlDataSource. ERROR: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Debe declarar la variable escalar '@EXPEDIENTE'.'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio

soy bastante novato y he empezado a trabajar hace poco desarrollando una aplicación web , no tengo mucha experiencia así que si sois capaces de resolver el problema y explicarlo de forma detallada estaría mucho más que agradecido. Estoy intentando insertar en visual Studio mediante un Gridview una serie de datos en mi base de datos. Para ello tengo varias textbox y un dropdownlist en la FooterRow para obtener una serie de datos y los otros datos que faltan en el insert los obtengo mirando otros GridViews/haciendo consultas a la base de datos. Al final , después de obtener de forma satisfactoria todos los datos que necesito para hacer el insert mediante el SqlDataSource, me dispongo a insertar los datos con cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); Pero al intentar hacerlo me sale este error:  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Debe declarar la variable escalar '@EXPEDIENTE'.'

El código de mi gridview es :

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="723px" ShowFooter="True" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" DataKeyNames="EXPEDIENTE,NUMERO_COMENTARIO" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView3_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EXPEDIENTE" SortExpression="EXPEDIENTE">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EXPEDIENTE") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EXPEDIENTE") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" OnClick="Click_addUser" >Añadir Comentario</asp:LinkButton>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NUMERO_COMENTARIO" SortExpression="NUMERO_COMENTARIO">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NUMERO_COMENTARIO") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NUMERO_COMENTARIO") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FECHA" SortExpression="FECHA">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FECHA") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FECHA") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="FECHA" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="COMENTARIO" SortExpression="COMENTARIO">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("COMENTARIO") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("COMENTARIO") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="COMENTARIO" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="USUARIO" SortExpression="USUARIO">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("USUARIO") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("USUARIO") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="NOMBRE_USUARIO" 
        DataValueField="NOMBRE_USUARIO" AppendDataBoundItems="True" ></asp:DropDownList>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DESAConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT A.ID_EXPE EXPEDIENTE,A.ID_COEX NUMERO_COMENTARIO, convert(varchar, A.FECHA_COMENTARIO, 3 ) FECHA, A.COMENTARIO,E.NOMBRE_USUARIO USUARIO FROM COEX_COMENTARIOS_EXPEDIENTES A , EXPE_EXPEDIENTES B,CLIE_CLIENTES C,EXCL_EXPEDIENTES_CLIENTES D,USUA_USUARIOS E WHERE A.ID_EXPE = B.ID_EXPE AND B.ID_EXPE=D.ID_EXPE AND C.ID_CLIENTE=D.ID_CLIENTE AND E.ID_USUA=A.ID_USUA;" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [COEX_COMENTARIOS_EXPEDIENTES] WHERE ([ID_EXPE] = @EXPEDIENTE) AND ([ID_COEX] = @NUMERO_COMENTARIO)"
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [COEX_COMENTARIOS_EXPEDIENTES] ([ID_EXPE], [ID_COEX], [FECHA_COMENTARIO], [COMENTARIO], [ID_USUA]) VALUES (@EXPEDIENTE,@NUMERO_COMENTARIO,@FECHA,COMENTARIO,@USUARIO)"
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [COEX_COMENTARIOS_EXPEDIENTES] SET [COMENTARIO] = @COMENTARIO, [ID_USUA] =(SELECT ID_USUA FROM USUA_USUARIOS WHERE NOMBRE_USUARIO=@USUARIO) WHERE [ID_EXPE] = @EXPEDIENTE AND [ID_COEX] = @NUMERO_COMENTARIO">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID_EXPE" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID_COEX" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID_EXPE" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID_COEX" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="FECHA_COMENTARIO" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="COMENTARIO" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID_USUA" Type="Int32" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="FECHA_COMENTARIO" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="COMENTARIO" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID_USUA" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID_EXPE" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID_COEX" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Y el código del proceso que se ejecuta cuando le doy a añadir/insertar es :

```
protected void Click_addUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool conected = false;

    try
    {
        conection.Close();
        conection.Open();
        conected = true;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        string errorconection = ex.Message;
    }
    
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)GridView3.FooterRow;
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)gvr.FindControl("DropDownList1");
  //  String nombre_usua = ((DropDownList)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("USUARIO")).Text;
    String nombre_usua=ddl.SelectedValue;
    String id_usua;
    String sSql = "select ID_USUA FROM USUA_USUARIOS WHERE NOMBRE_USUARIO='" + nombre_usua + "'";

    SqlDataSource5.SelectCommand = sSql;
    DataView dv = (DataView)SqlDataSource5.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    id_usua=dv.Table.Rows[0][0].ToString();

    sSql = "select ID_EXPE FROM EXPE_EXPEDIENTES WHERE ID_EXPE="+GridView2.Rows[1].Cells[0].Text+"";
    SqlDataSource6.SelectCommand = sSql;
    dv = (DataView)SqlDataSource6.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    string id_Expe=dv.Table.Rows[0][0].ToString();

    sSql = "select MAX(ID_COEX)+1 from COEX_COMENTARIOS_EXPEDIENTES where ID_EXPE="+id_Expe+"";
    SqlDataSource7.SelectCommand = sSql;
    dv = (DataView)SqlDataSource7.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    string id_Coex = dv.Table.Rows[0][0].ToString();


    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [COEX_COMENTARIOS_EXPEDIENTES] ([ID_EXPE], [ID_COEX], [FECHA_COMENTARIO], [COMENTARIO], [ID_USUA]) VALUES (@EXPEDIENTE, @NUMERO_COMENTARIO, @FECHA, @COMENTARIO,@USUARIO)", conection);

    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@EXPEDIENTE";
    param.Value = id_Expe;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

    SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@NUMERO_COMENTARIO";
    param.Value = id_Coex;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);

    SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@FECHA";
    param.Value = ((TextBox)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("FECHA")).Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param3);

    SqlParameter param4 = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@COMENTARIO";
    param.Value = ((TextBox)GridView3.FooterRow.FindControl("COMENTARIO")).Text; ;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param4);


    SqlParameter param5 = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@USUARIO";
    param.Value = id_usua;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param5);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();}
```

el error salta en el cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Me estoy volviendo loco tratando de encontrar una solución , si alguien pudiese ayudarme se lo agradecería muchísimo.

Comment: Parece que los nombres de tus parámetros no coinciden con los que usas en tus comandos de SQL.

Comment: @LuisCazares a que te refieres? Tengo una columna en el gridview llamada EXPEDIENTE que contiene el valor ID_EXPE de la base de datos. Se tienen que llamar igual?